# How can I attribute tracked changes to a different reviewer/author name?

Tags: microsoft-word, rename, microsoft-office-2010, review

I was using MS Word on someone's computer to make tracked changes to some document. Now, the document has changes attributed to "Alex" (me) but also to "Bob" (other person). How can I reassign all of "Bob"'s changes in the file to "Alex"?

Note: I don't want to *accept* the changes, just change the attribution.

Note: It's Office 2010, but if you have a solution using another version, that might also be relevant.

Comment: As far as I know, it uses the name of user who is using the computer currently. If you want to use a different reviewer/author name, you need to log out the computer and log in other user account on the computer.

Comment: @HerbGu_MSFT: That is for _new_ reviewer comments. I want to change the user on _existing_ comments. Also, to change the name for new comments you can use the Word app options.